# access to specific settings in production

Tags: user-groups, settings

thanks for any advice in advance.  I agree with craftcms that in production mode access to setting should be off limits. With that being said in the users tab on the dashboard I have not seen anywhere to be able to add the ability for admins to create user groups. Only by accessing the setting can you create new user groups. It seems that if you change allowAdminChanges to true it allows access to change all settings. As I'm only after the ability to create new user groups is it possible to only add access to specific portions of the settings? or does anyone know how to add the capability to the user tab in the dashboard to add user groups?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, and even if it were it would break deployments because your project config in your repository would get out of sync with the production site, so any deployment would remove the newly created user groups. Why do you need to create new user groups so frequently? It's likely you're misusing user groups for something they're not intended to do. If you need more granular permissions, you can always do that for individual users. If you need to distinguish between types of users, you can use a category field so that new categories can be added in production …

Comment: So I'll give you a example of the website I am currently working on, It is educational in its nature, So they need the ability to group a set of users by intake and be able to track dates of training in the backend for the administrator/teacher.  As it is educational groups are constantly being made and eventually removed content that is specific to a user group. i've also run into issues for instance with contact form where a persons email address changes so in order them to change the contact form email they have contact me to do, because there is no settings access at all.